# How to POST a query and GET results using httr R

Tags: r, post, get, httr

I am new to httr and am having some issues, and followed https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/vignettes/quickstart.html and https://www.r-bloggers.com/using-the-httr-package-to-retrieve-data-from-apis-in-r/ and [R: posting search forms and scraping results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25100753/r-posting-search-forms-and-scraping-results).

I want to determine my child's percentile mass from https://www.infantchart.com/, and need to input 5 values: 
sex
birthday
measure date
weight, and
unit.

I would like to scrape percentile and age

I tried:

```
r <- POST("https://www.infantchart.com/", 
         body = list(Gender = "male", Birthday = "10/04/2017",'Measure Date'='04/10/2018',Weight='7.7',Unit='kg')
         )
```

to no avail

I also tried to inspect the webpage to find the names of the sections in the webpage ie (radiofield-1005-inputE1,datefield-1014-inputE1,datefield-1017-inputE1,numberfield-1020-inputE1,radiofield-1024-inputE1), also to no avail.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: This does not work because the chart and the data are generated dynamically on the client side. You are trying to send data to the server.

Comment: That said, you could use `RSelenium` to simulate a client who is filling in the variables in a browser session.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will read up RSelenium